# How exactly setup a RoR channel to send data back and forth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I'm trying to simulate grammarly spell checking with the help of ActionCable, but I'm struggling a bit to understand how to

- setup authentication
- broadcast data back and forth

I read many articles, including the official docs, and yet I feel confused. So, the first thing I did was add the following to my `config/application.rb`:

```
    # Mount ActionCable.
    config.action_cable.mount_path = '/websocket'
```

I also setup authentication:

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end

    private

    def find_verified_user
      current_user = User.find_by_api_key(token)
      if current_user
        current_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end

    def token
      # TODO: verify if this is really safe.
      request.headers[:AUTHORIZATION].split('=').last
    end
  end
end
```

I do not use `device`, and my authentication is **token** based. Each user has a fixed API token, that's it.

Hopefully that authentication is correct, I would appreciate if someone with more experienced could point me if this is not right.

Now, I've created a channel called `spell_checking_channel`:

```
class SpellCheckingChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from 'spell_checking_channel_' << current_user.id
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end
```

Once I receive data from the frontend, I would like to call `SpellChecker.call('text')` and broadcast back to it with the results. I know, it's ridiculous that I'm asking for help with this, but I'm truly not finding an example for it. Also, should I do anything on the `unsubscribed` method?

Answer (score 1):

ActionCable is wrapper around WebSockets, on websocket connection browser passes the same cookies as it does to regular requests, that's why devise and similar cookie-based auth methods work. For token-based auth it's easier to pass the token in params like so:

```js
const my_token = '...';
const cable = ActionCable.createConsumer(`/websocket?token=${my_token}`);
```

it will be in `request.params[:token]` in connection.

In your js send data to channel:

```js
const channel = cable.subscriptions.create({ channel: "SpellCheckingChannel" }, {
  received(data) {
    // handle data from channel in some way
    console.log("received from rails:", data);
  }
});

channel.send({ some_data_to_rails: "goes_here" })
```

on backend:

```rb
class SpellCheckingChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    # here we instruct ActionCable to send messages from following topic
    stream_from "spell_checking_channel_#{current_user.id}"
    # there may be multiple subscriptions in one channel:
    stream_from "spell_checking_channel_common"
  end

  def receive(data)
    # channel.send(data) ends up here

    ActionCable.server.broadcast("spell_checking_channel_#{current_user.id}", { this_goes_back: "to js" })

    if data[:foo] == "bar"
      ActionCable.server.broadcast("spell_checking_channel_common", { hey_listen_all: "lala" })
    end
  end
end
```

main trick is that you can use `ActionCable.server.broadcast` from anywhere in your app, not only in channels, for example - in channel you can enqueue a background job, that will send its result to the channel

Comment: Can I send the token through a header instead?

Comment: @AmandaFerrari WebSocket api in browsers does not support that

Comment: I see. Thank you for the clear answer! I'm going to test it, and assuming it works I will accept your answer.

Comment: Should I do anything with the `unsubscribe` method?

Comment: @AmandaFerrari only if you need to cleanup something (like external resources, periodic timers and so on, everything that could have continued to do something for a user who’s already gone), for most basic use cases you do not need this

Comment: I found very weird the need to call `stream_from "name"` and then again `ActionCable.server.broadcast("name")`. If would be really nice to just call `send` or something else.

Comment: @AmandaFerrari several channels may stream from a single key/topic, also this way senders are not aware of the channels. This is good old pub-sub. For example topic can be like “users_from_group-1” and one `broadcast` will deliver to multiple channels, which subscribed to it

Comment: I don't fully get it. I create a stream with a name "name" and then a broadcast from a channel with the name "name"? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @AmandaFerrari think of it like of radios and radio stations: each station is broadcasting something(server.broadcast), and a radio(channel) can tune in (stream from).